# Elastic Search bulk upload not inheriting predefined mapping

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to upload JSON content into Elastic using the [bulk upload](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) method however the situation is that the exporting application that creates said JSON doesn't exactly give out clean JSON. An example:

```
{ 
   ...
   "filesize" : "123456"
}
```

When I bulk upload this Elastic interprets the field "filesize" as a string, so I decided to try and [create a mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) so that Elastic attempts to read it as an integer. I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way of doing things as I'm not convinced the field mapping enforces casting from string to number, but nonetheless it was worth a shot.

My mapping is this:

```
PUT /my_index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_item": {
      "properties": {
        "sub_item_a": {
          "properties" :{
            "sub_item_b": {
              "properties": {
                "filesize": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After creating this mapping, I checked the mapping via this:

```
GET /my_index/my_item/_mapping
```

This confirmed the mapping was in place, so I imported the data, checked the mapping again and confirmed it's still correct (and is correctly nested amidst all the other content that is dynamically analysed).

But when I go to the Discover dashboard in Kibana the content for the filesize field is still an analysed text field. This is a problem as I want to use it as bucketed numbers in Kibana visualisations.

I tried to combat this with a bit of regex on the JSON files to make it so that it reads without quotes surrounding the integer:

```
{ 
   ...
   "filesize" : 123456
}
```

Then I did the whole delete index/create mapping/re-upload process again and the same result occurred: Elastic is still convinced it's a text field.

Am I doing something horribly wrong? Or have I missed a piece of pertinent information that means this won't work?

I know I can achieve results via LogStash but I'm trying to remove any processing steps to streamline this part of the application being built.

For the record:

Elastic Version - 2.2.0

Kibana Version - 4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.

Basically when deleting the index I just ran a "DELETE my_index". When attempting to reupload the data the mappings and all the other associated stuff stayed the same.

I just ran a "DELETE _all", then did my mapping, then reuploaded the data, then created the new index, and now it all works fine.

Comment: Can someone be more precise what is meant by `DELETE _all`?

Comment: @Dror In Kibana Sense, run "delete _all" and it will drop all indexes (and saved data such as Dashboards etc so be sure to back those up).